# Unable to reference Xamarin.Forms in brand new project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to write a Xamarin Forms example for the PCL based socket implementation. The project will not build due to not being able to resolve 'Forms'. The Project is brand new (5/27/2015) and I have yet to add any custom code or packages to it. I am using Xamarin Forms 1.4.2. If I remove the MainView.xaml the project will build. Main View is default with no custom code.

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Websocket.Portable.Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (Websocket.Portable.Xamarin)

Other Xamarin projects build and run fine, but, I am unable to create anything new.

[image]
[Project Download](http://cd8ba0b44a15c10065fd-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/c8/cc300fadc0fc10d6b2871899df7e53.zip)

Comment: Same problem, what was the resolved namespace for missing references?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a namespace conflict. You have `Xamarin` in your namespace and the compiler is confused. Adjust your namespace so that it does not include `Xamarin`.

To be safe, **do not use** the following words in your namespaces:

- `Xamarin`
- `Android`
- `iOS`

You can use the following safely:

- `Droid`
- `iPhone`
- `iPad`
- `Universal` (or even `iOSUniversal`)
- `Shared`
- `Common`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going crazy for a little bit.